# Binding Nullable Bit (in DB) to CheckBox ASP.Net Web Forms Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

Im leveraging model binding in my ASP.Net WebForms application, facing problem while binding nullable bit to checkbox, in my aspx page  i have something like

```
<li>IS A ChkBox</li>
   <li>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="someid" runat="server"
                  MaxLength="100" Checked='<%# BindItem.databaseValue%>'>
     </asp:CheckBox>                        
   </li>
```

initially when the form is populated the value is null and i get a `NullReferenceException`, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, how can i get around this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab

Checked='<%# BindItem.databaseValue ?? false %>'

I think this works with Item (AKA Eval) anyway.  CheckBox is weird.